# JQuery Select2 - how to configure the ID to be predictable

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jquery-select2, e2e-testing, testcafe

I’ve searched here and in the Select2 forum and I’ve found just one answer regarding the issues related to test automation and the dynamic nature of ID that are generated by Select2.
AFAIK at my company, we are using Select2 integrated with Bootstrap 3.7 and for some Select2 use cases we have got same findings done here -> https://medium.com/@kcmueller.

I’m preparing a webinar regarding test automation using TestCafe & TestCafe Studio and when trying to use this -> Select2 Github ChangeLog Page as a playground, I’ve seen that on select with option groups, id are created in what seems a random/dynamic way, making impossible any kind of automation that does not depends on finding/clicking things by position.

In addition, I’m not able to find documentation that explains how the ID of the main select2 element is generated. In the Select2 example page id is s2id_e1 for a plain select with id e1.

[image]

I’m very confused, because I’m not able to find any documentation that will allow me to understand what is the algorithm used, if algorithm changes according the select characteristics: single selection, multiple selection, option groups.

Hope my explanation is clear.
Any hint?
Any documentation?
Any option other to develop some kind of adapter, as I’ve read in the only post I’ve found regarding test automation?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's possible to make Select2 to generate consistent IDs, but it's not a problem if you are using TestCafe. TestCafe provides a lot of ways to locate an item despite its ID and position. For example, the item highlighted in the screenshot can be accessed via `Selector('.select2-choice > span').withExactText('Alaska')`. The full description of TestCafe selectors can be found [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/).

Comment: Thanks, this can work in some situations, but if you need to test with localization (Alaska is not the best example), you need to change the text you need to search according to the language used on User Interface. Having the possibility to access a fixed ID that has the code IMHO will be better.